# How to create a rolling window with fixed length in Spark Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to implement a fixed-size rolling windows in Spark but I cannot find a way to do this.

For example, with a windows that as a `rangeBetween(-3, 3)` and that would have a fixed size of `3`, the result would have be:

| # | partition | ordered_column | **Rows in windows** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 12 | **1,2,3** |
| 2 | A | 13 | **1,2,3** |
| 3 | A | 14 | **1,2,3** |
| 4 | A | 15 | **1,2,3** |
| 5 | A | 16 | **2,3,4** |

Is it possible to do this with native Spark window functions?

I tried to do it by using `ordered_column` as a time column and using `windowDuration` and `slideDuration` but was not able to obtain the expected result.